# Why clang doesn't issued a warning with using uninitialized array?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I was reading some code from a book,and forget to initialize the array marbles.But I get no warning from clang.
here is the code:

```
/* sum_arr2.c -- 对一个数组的所有元素求和 */
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int sump(int *start,int * end);

int main(void)
{
    int marbles[SIZE];
    long answer;

    answer = sump(marbles,marbles + SIZE);
    printf("The total number of marbles is %ld.\n",answer);
    return 0;
}

/* 使用指针算术 */
int sump(int * start,int * end)
{
    int total = 0;

    while(start < end)
    {
            total +=*start; /* 把值累加到total上*/
            start++;        /* 把指针向前推进到下一个元素 */
    }
    return total;
}
```

I compiled the code with:

```
gcc -Wall sum_arr2.c
```

and got no warning.
   so I tried

```
clang -Wall sum_arr2.c
```

still no warning.
when I executed the program

```
./a.out
```

The output is some random value.

### so I want to ask  is it a correct behavior of the compiler, Or a bug?

It seems gcc is just a name not the really gcc compiler:

```
gcc -v

Configured with: --     prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

can anyone test it on gcc ?

Comment: Do you have more warnings with `gcc -W -Wall sum_arr2.c` ?

Comment: GCC produces a warning with `-O3`.

Answer (score 3):

Most compilers will only look into one function at a time when they are generating warnings and if you don't look inside the implementation of `sump` you can't know that the call inside `main` is wrong. What if `sump` wrote to the array instead of reading from it? In that case passing an uninitialized array would not be a problem.

```
int sump(int * start,int * end)
{
    while(start < end)
    {
        *start = 42;
        start++;
    }
    return 17;
}
```